# How to retrieve objects that are not created by the user?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

This question might be weird, but i want to retrieve objects except  the objects created by the login in user

Well  i tried this code in my view

```
def getobjects(request):
    products=Products.objects.filter(user!= request.user)
```

But does not work.

In model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name=models.Charfield()
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I will need help with the right query function to handle this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude request user

```
products=Products.objects.exclude(user = request.user)
```

Comment: i get this error ,"name 'user' is not defined"

Comment: try this `.exclude(user_id = request.user.pk)` and make sure your request has user object.

Comment: By which example? I mean solution from comment or question?

Comment: from your answer.